# JQuery UI, dialog creates a dialog, hit escape and the first dialog exits

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-dialog

I have a Login dialog that can create an alert dialog when the user does not fill in all the fields. Then hitting escape removes the login dialog not the alert dialog.

jquery-1.7.2.js
jqueryui-1.8.18.js

```
// alert popup
function alertMsg(szMsg)
{
    $('#alertText').html(szMsg);
    $('#alertPopup').dialog('open');
}

$('#alertPopup').dialog({
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 360,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    show: 'scale',
    hide: 'scale',
    buttons: {
        "OK": function() { 
            $(this).dialog("close"); 
        } 
    }
});

// login dialog
$('#loginDialog').dialog({
    open: function() {
        $('#company').focus();
    },
    autoOpen: false,
    width: 360,
    resizable: false,
    modal: true,
    show: 'scale',
    hide: 'scale',
    buttons: {
        "Login": function() { 
            var szCompany = $('#company').val();
            var szUser = $('#user').val();
            var szPassword = $('#password').val();

            if ((/^\s*$/).test(szCompany) ||
                            (/^\s*$/).test(szUser) ||
                            (/^\s*$/).test(szPassword))
            {
                // this is the alert call that creates the bug
                alertMsg('You need to fill in Company, User,' +
                                ' and Password');
            }
            else
            {
                $(this).dialog("close"); 
                alertMsg(szUser + ' (who works for ' +
                        szCompany + ' and has a secret password of ' +
                        szPassword + ', which is no longer a secret)' +
                        ' check back soon for a real login experience.');
            }
        }, 
        "Cancel": function() { 
            $(this).dialog("close"); 
        } 
    }
});

// handle enter key for login dialog
$('#loginDialog').find('input').keypress(function(e) {
    if ((e.which && e.which == 13) || (e.keyCode && e.keyCode == 13)) {
        $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().
            find('.ui-dialog-buttonpane').find('button:first').click();
        return false;
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set the "closeOnEscape" option to false in the login dialog, and true on the alert dialog (it is true by default)

Comment: then how would I get closeOnEscape re-enabled in the login dialog after the alert is closed?

Comment: Also, after the first escape removes the login dialog, a second escape does not remove the alert.

Comment: On the close event handler of the alert dialog, you can set the closeOnEscape property of the login dialog as true. `code`close: function(event, ui) { $("#loginDialog").dialog("option", "closeOnEscape", false); }`code`.

Comment: Progress: It is now all working great except that the alert will not close with the escape key, I even tried explicitly setting closeOnEscape to true.
What will be the best way to reference the dialog to reenable it's closeOnEscape in the alert so that the alert can work for other dialogs?

Comment: Note: If I do the alert from the "login" button instead of launching the login dialog, it closes on escape correctly.